# Подключение COM-объекта на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, com

Пишу программу на Python,

Windows 7 Профессиональная 64bit

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Simatic.Simatic")
```

Запускаю, после чего, он на меня так ругается:

```
PythonWin 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32.
Portions Copyright 1994-2008 Mark Hammond - see 'Help/About PythonWin' for further copyright information.
>>> C:\Users\and\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\re.py:203: FutureWarning: split() requires a non-empty pattern match.
  return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\and\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 89, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, 'Операция недоступна', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\and\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 323, in RunScript
    debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=0)
  File "C:\Users\and\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
    _GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
  File "C:\Users\and\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 654, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "C:\Users\and\Desktop\Test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import win32com.client
  File "C:\Users\and\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "C:\Users\and\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Users\and\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221164, 'Класс не зарегистрирован', None, None)
>>>
```

Регистрировал компонент так:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corp.), 2009. Все права защищены.

C:\Windows\system32>regsvr32.exe "c:\Program Files (x86)\Siemens\Step7\S7BIN\S7A
BATCX.DLL"

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Регистрация прошла успешно

[image: COM объект в реестре и браузере объектов]

Почему он не зарегистрирован?
VBA excel без проблем к нему коннектится

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что у вас 64-битная операционная система и разрядность COM-компонента не совпадает с разрядностью Python.

Comment: Да, у меня 64-битная win7 и стоял python 3.5 64bit. Однако попробовал я на python 3.5 32bit - такая же ошибка выскакивает: